# QueryDSL JPA Insert

Tags: java, querydsl

How to insert row in table using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For update I found JPAUpdateClause
For delete I found JPADeleteClause

But how to insert row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QueryDSL only supposer the `DELETE` and `UPDATE` - you will have to use the `Hibernate or JPA` to insert your entities.

Answer (score 2):

Since may 2020 QueryDsl JPA now support insert statements.

See this pull request, that was merged on may 28th: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2421